# Is there a way to remove permissions from a role on creation with Discord?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to remove all the permissions from a role that my bot has made on the server, I've looked on Discord JS guide and other websites but there's nothing about it on there, Im basically stuck here's my code:

```js
if (!message.guild.roles.cache.find(i => i.name == 'Muted')) {
    message.channel.send('Adding \`Muted\` Role...')
    await message.guild.roles.create({
        data: {
            name: 'Muted',
            color: '#ff4939',
            permissions: ["ALL", false]
        },
        reason: 'Mute role automaticly added.',
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all permissions from a role on creation, provide an empty array.

```js
await message.guild.roles.create({
    data: {
        name: 'Muted',
        color: '#ff4939',
        permissions: [] //should have no permissions
    },
    reason: 'Mute role automaticly added.',
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`permissions: new Discord.Permissions()` should give no permissions, since it works the same as the permissions calculator. Permissions can be either a `string`, `number`, `array` or made by the `Permissions` constructor using bits.

[PermissionResolvable - v12](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.5.3/typedef/PermissionResolvable)

Comment: `permissions: 0` said `Invalid bitfield flag or number` for me. I tried it before empty array

Comment: Weird, on the docs even the Permissions constructor defaults to 0 for no perms, perhaps it'd prefer you use that then, but yeah the empty array works too

Comment: that's what I thought... I was surprised when it didn't work

Comment: Upon some testing, it seems using a blank `new Discord.Permissions()` will work but not `new Discord.Permissions(0)` or `permissions:0`

Comment: @LocationCoder comments are not for conversations. They are for clarification. And yes I have a discord but idk about making a project, I don't think so